# How can we solve this composer installation issue with php-parser

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-parser

I am using Ubuntu 14 and Nginx. I'm getting this error when trying to install PHP-Parser.

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for h4cc/phpqatools 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by h4cc/phpqatools[1.1.0].
    - Installation request for theseer/phpdox 0.5.*@dev -> satisfiable by theseer/phpdox[0.5.x-dev].
    - don't install nikic/php-parser 1.0.x-dev|install nikic/php-parser dev-master
    - theseer/phpdox 0.5.x-dev requires nikic/php-parser >=1.0.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[dev-master, 1.0.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install nikic/php-parser dev-master
```

Comment: I'd try deleting `conooser.lock`, it usually helps